# Search Pivot table for field to show detail if not found create new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA code that will open a certain Pivot field's details on a new page or if that field is not found in the pivot table, will create a new sheet that will be named what that field was supposed to be named. I keep getting compile error: End if without block if what am I missing?  It also seems to just completely ignore the show details for the pivot field and just creates a new sheet with nothing on it. Help is greatly appreciated This is what I have so far:

```
Sub
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="+ Deposit", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Deposits"
Else: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Deposits"
End If

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="- Withdrawal", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Withdrawals"
Else: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Withdrawals"
End If

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="- Check", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
Range(A).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
Sheets("Sheet7").Name = "Checks"
Else: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet7").Name = "Checks"
End If

EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax needs to be more like this:

```
Sub subName()

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="+ Deposit", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
    Range(A).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
    Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Deposits"
Else
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Deposits"
End If

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="- Withdrawal", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
    Range(A).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
    Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Withdrawals"
Else
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Withdrawals"
End If

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="- Check", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
If A = Found.Address Then
    Range(A).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
    Sheets("Sheet7").Name = "Checks"
Else
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("Sheet7").Name = "Checks"
End If

End Sub
```

But you aren't specifying what it is "A" is.  I assume that's some specific value that you'll be looking for and will replace on your side for testing.

One thing to note is that the macro recorder doesn't capture every functionality of Excel.    Things like Freeze Panes tend to only behave right in very particular ways, I imagine that pivot tables may not be friendly with show detail.  What you might try is specifying the cell directly instead of selecting it first.  In other words:

```
On Error Resume Next
foundRow = Cells.Find(What:="+ Deposit", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
On Error Goto 0
If foundRow > 1 Then
    Cells(foundRow, 3).ShowDetail = True
    '...assuming "ShowDetail" created a new sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Deposits"
Else
```